# How to use a powershell custom object variable in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, powershell

Im trying to make a script which takes data from serval places in our network and centralize them in one database. At the moment I'm trying to take data from AD and but it in my database but i get some weird outcome.

```
function Set-ODBC-Data{
  param(
  [string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.')
  )
  $cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$DBConnection)
  $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$DBConnection = $null
$DBConnected = $FALSE
try{
    $DBConnection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=pcinventory;User=uSR;Password=PpPwWwDdD;Port=3306"
    $DBConnection.Open()
    $DBConnected = $TRUE
    Write-Host "Connected to the MySQL database."
}
catch{
    Write-Host "Unable to connect to the database..."
}

$ADEMEA = "ADSERVER.SERVER.WORK"
$addata = Get-ADComputer -filter * -property Name,CanonicalName,LastLogonDate,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion -Server $ADEMEA | Select-Object Name,CanonicalName,LastLogonDate,IPv4Address,OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion

    ForEach($aditem in $addata){


        Set-ODBC-Data -query "INSERT INTO ad VALUES( '$aditem.Name', '','','','','' )"

    }
```

The result in my database looks someting like this

[image: db result]

Comment: I fixed it by putting the custom objects in a variable and using that variable in the query

Answer (score 0):

This happens, as `$aditem` is a custom Powershell object, and the SQL insert query doesn't quite know how to handle it. The outcome is a hashtable (aka key-value store) containing objects' attributes and attribute values.

As for fix, the good one is to use parametrized queries.

As for quick and dirty work-around that makes SQL injection easy, build insert string in a few parts. Using string formatting `{}` and `-f` makes it quite simple. Like so,

```
$q = "INSERT INTO ad VALUES( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}' )" -f $aditem.name, "more", "stuff"
write-host "Query: $q" # For debugging purposes
Set-ODBC-Data -query $q
```

The problem in quick and dirty is, as mentioned SQL injection. Consider what happens if the input is

```
$aditem.name, "more", "'); drop database pcinventory; --"
```

If the syntax is about right and permissions are adequate, it will execute the insertion. Right after that, it will drop your `pcinventory` database. So don't be tempted to use the fast approach, unless you are sure about what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is that it only adds one row with {0} {1} {2} if i use 

Set-ODBC-Data -query "INSERT INTO ad VALUES( '{0}', '{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}' )" -f $aditem.Name, $aditem.CanonicalName, $aditem.LastLogonDate, $aditem.IPv4Address, $aditem.OperatingSystem, $aditem.OperatingSystemVersion

Comment: @claeys What do you mean by one row? The command's in a foreach loop, isn't it? Does the `write-host` part print sensible insert statements?